# SQL for categorization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name customer where a customer has unique customer id. A customer ID can have multiple booking numbers which are unique. I have to find:

1. Number of customers having only basic type booking versus Number of only additional type
2. Number of customers having additional type that are also basic

| Customer ID | Booking number | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | Basic |
| 123 | 2 | Additional |
| 123 | 3 | Basic |
| 456 | 4 | Basic |
| 678 | 5 | Additional |
| 789 | 6 | Additional |
| 789 | 7 | Basic |
| 1011 | 8 | Additional |

Output

| Type | Number of customers |
| --- | --- |
| Only Basic | 1 |
| Only Additional | 2 |
| Both | 2 |

Comment: Mysql and hiveql aren't the same thing. Which are you using? (please edit and update your question)

Comment: Can you share [the code you already tried and where you're stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us?

Comment: please share the output structure with data from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

To check how many `basic` or `additional` bookings a customer has is just a conditional sum..

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'basic'      THEN 1 END)   AS count_basic,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'additional' THEN 1 END)   AS count_additional
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  customer_id
```

Then, you can use that as a sub-query, and categorise the customers.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN count_basic      = 0 THEN 'Only Additional'
       WHEN count_additional = 0 THEN 'Only Basic'
                                 ELSE 'Both'            END AS category,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'basic'      THEN 1 END)   AS count_basic,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'additional' THEN 1 END)   AS count_additional
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    customer_id 
)
  AS customer_summary
GROUP BY
  1
```

Please forgive typos, I'm on my phone.